# cant save diagram as pptx (PowerPoint)

Tags: jquery, powerpoint, extract, diagram, devextreme

dx-diagram library to create a diagram and with the FileSaver Library to save that file as pptx after finishing the drawing and there is another button to extract it as json  but it kept show error where that is the code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="../jQuery3.7.1.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/dx-diagram.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/dx-diagram.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/dx.light.css">
    <script src="js/dx-diagram.js"></script>
    <script src="js/dx-diagram.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/dx.all.js"></script>
  <scripttype="text/javascript"src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/FileSaver.js/1.3.8/FileSaver.js"></script>
    <script src="data.js"></script>
    <script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#diagram').dxDiagram();
    var diagram = $('#diagram').dxDiagram("instance");
    $('#normal-contained').click(function() {
      diagram.exportTo("pptx", function(res) {
    saveAs(res.blob, "diagram.pptx");
    console.log(res);
      });
    });
  $('#jsonFile').click(function() {
      diagram.export();
      });
    });
  });
</script>
```

But it gave me this error every time I press on that button

I tried every solution on dev express web site and it wont work. Does any one know the solution of that problem [consul error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uy2PW.png)

> Uncaught TypeError: cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'type')